# "One of my desires in life is to meet you up directly at least once in my lifetime"

Tags: grammar

Is this statement grammatically correct?

> One of my desires in life is to meet you up directly at least once in my lifetime.

Comment: Do you intend to imply that  your _life_ and your _lifetime_ are different? If not, why mention both of them?

Comment: My doubt is whether the whole statement is grammatically correct or not... what is your suggestion of it? What can be edited? if it's wrong, how it can be rephrased?

Comment: Don't say _meet you up directly_. Say _meet with you personally_. And drop _in life_, since you've only got one lifetime.

Comment: I tell you one scenario. How should it be if I'm writing it to a famous personality?

Comment: @JohnLawler, he could be a Buddhist who forgot the 'this' for "in this life" and the plural for "lifetime".

Comment: "One of my most fervent desires is to meet you."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my lifetime is not required - '*life*' itself is already mentioned at the beginning of the sentence, and a meet-up session is only possible when you are alive (duh), so it is unnecessary to have 'in my lifetime' at the back of your sentence.

'Meet you up directly' is structured wrongly, a better way to phrase it would be, for example, 'a direct meet-up with you' or 'personal meet-up', it depends on the sentence.

So there you have it, a better phrased sentence which encompasses the same meaning would be:

> One of my desires in my life is to have at least one personal meet-up with you.